# How to properly unescape the STDOUT from the PostgreSQL COPY syntax via python/psycopg2's copy_expert

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I stream jsonb objects from a postgres table as a large `application/jsonl` http response. This works really well:

```
def stream_json_from_copy_syntax():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    file = BytesIO()
    cur.copy_expert(
        sql="COPY (select my_jsonb from large_table) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT text)",
        file=file
    )
    file.seek(0)
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = unescape(line)
        yield line
```

The above is pushed into a Flask response. This is fast, and has a very low memory footprint.

The jsonb field is initially properly escaped, but it seems the `(FORMAT text)` is adding some extra escaping.

This turns `My \ string` into the propper json `"My \\ string"` and then into `"My \\\\ string"`. So there is an extra escaping going on. I've handled this for now with:

```
def unescape(line):
    return line.replace(b'\\\\', b'\\')
```

I think this solves most issues, if not all, but I'm a litte unsure if there are other things the `(FORMAT text)` is escaping which I haven't handled.

How do I properly unescape what `(FORMAT text)` does? Or is there a way not to let it escape anything at all, because the initial json escaping works fine.

Note that using `(ESCAPE 'escape_character')` only applies to `(FORMAT csv)`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting data in the format that Postgres COPY...FROM would understand. Maybe you need a different format, such as CSV.

Comment: Do you know if there exists an postgres unescape library or maybe the actual codebase which postgres uses to parse text formatted files, in which I could reimplement in python? But yeah. Maybe if I over-configure the CSV version. When I tried it naively it gave me a bunch of extra quotes, but that can maybe be removed.

Comment: You could use psycopg 3 and obtain the objects in Python, then you format them as you want.